# "Show in Folder" isn't first item when right clicking Downloads

Tags: firefox

I want to have "Show in Folder" on top of the right click Downloads menu of Firefox 95.0. It's the functionality I use most to access my downloads so it would be very convenient if it were the first item in the list.

[image: screenshot of Firefox Downloads menu]

Answer (score 0):

There's a `menu editor` add-on for Firefox. It lets you edit the Firefox menus. There's also this [custom right click menu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/custom-right-click-menu/)

Those let you build the menus the way you want, according to your own style of browsing.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without add-ons? I don't like the security risk of using 3rd party add-ons and the one you linked to has some negative reviews. I'm not trying to invalidate your answer, but I was expecting a solution with less risk.

Comment: There is a way to do it directly with the `about:config` page, but I wouldn't know how. The add-ons are security risks because they directly manipulate the `about:config` settings.  So there would be no difference doing it manually. And, the security risks are theoretical. Most add-ons are safe, and some, such as: `noscript` make browsing much safer!

Comment: Depending how complex it is (if it can be done) I would want to try the manual solution before considering installing anything. Maybe someone will post an answer explaining how.